# Sphinx erlang-domain extension

Tags: python, erlang, python-sphinx

I try to use Sphinx for documentation generating. And I need to Erlang code syntax highlighting. I found erlang-domain extension in sphinx-contrib. I made:

```
easy_install -U sphinxcontrib-erlangdomain
```

How can I include and use erlangdomain with sphinx? I put markup example from http://packages.python.org/sphinxcontrib-erlangdomain/, but I got errors (and other like this):

> ERROR: Unknown directive type "erl:function".

How can I include erlangdomain extensions in Sphinx?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add "sphinxcontrib.erlangdomain" to the [extensions](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/config.html#confval-extensions) configuration variable in conf.py:

```
extensions = ["sphinxcontrib.erlangdomain"]
```